# if else statement assignment

Tags: java, if-statement

edit : I reworked some of the code but I still can't get it to calculate a rate if the user enters less than a week. My new code is below. any assistance would be received with gratitude.
I have to write a code to simulate giving a car rental quote where the user inputs the color, amount of days to rent, and chooses between two types of vehicles. There are two rates for each type, one weekly, one daily. I then have to find the best rate and output it. When I input white, economy, and 4 in the code below it doesn't output anything. I think I have an error in the rate for less than a week but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab3
 {


    public static final double ECONOMY_DAILY = 25.5;
    public static final double FULL_DAILY = 39.4;
    public static final double ECONOMY_WEEKLY = 120.5;
    public static final double FULL_WEEKLY = 216.25;
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the color of the vehicle:");
            //string the next input as color
        String color = Keyboard.next();

        System.out.println ("Economy or Full:");
            // string the type of the vehicle
        String Type = Keyboard.next();
            // to get the character value to uppercase for the switch statement
        char FirstTypeLetter = Type.toUpperCase()
        .charAt(0); 
        System.out.println("For how many days?");
            //set days as the next integer entered and calculate the amount of weeks and daysleftover using the / and % operators
        int days = Keyboard.nextInt();
        int weeks = days/7;
        int daysLeftOver = days%7;
        double weeksRounded = ((days/7)*100)/100;

    double rate1,rate2,rate3;

        // create a switch using the variable defined earlier
    switch (FirstTypeLetter) 
    {
            // if the Type entry starts with an e
            case 'F':
                // calculate the 3 rates for full size using the full size constants (could have put this code anywhere above the next if statement.)
            rate1 = weeksRounded * FULL_WEEKLY;
            rate2 = (weeks * FULL_WEEKLY) + (days * FULL_DAILY);
           rate3 = (days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
           break;
        case 'E':
            // calculate all available rents for economy using the constants defined earlier
   rate1 = weeksRounded * ECONOMY_WEEKLY;
     rate2 = (weeks * ECONOMY_WEEKLY) + (days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
     rate3 = (days * ECONOMY_DAILY);

        break;
        default:
       System.out.println("Try Again!");
        rate1 = 0;
        rate2 = 0;
        rate3 = 0;
       }
            if ((rate1 < rate2) & (rate1 < rate3) & (rate1 != 0)) 
            {   
                    // print out the first rate as well as the color and type that the user entered
                System.out.printf("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + days + "days:" + "%.2f",rate1);
            }
                // if not, and if the second rate is cheapest
            if ((rate2 < rate1) & (rate2 < rate3) & (rate1 != 0))
            {
                    // print out the second rate as well as the color and type that the user entered
                System.out.printf("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + days + "days:" + "%.2f", rate2);
            }
                    // if the third rate is cheapest then print out that rate
            else if ((rate3 < rate2) & (rate3 < rate1) & (rate3 != 0)) 

                System.out.printf("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + days + "days:" + "%.2f", rate3);
            }



   }
```

Comment: Sure you do not want to add a `break` in `case F`?

Comment: Format your code and you'll see that everything until the first break is in your first if-block.

Comment: You should read the following [Code Conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) regarding the naming of variables. Names like these: `FirstTypeLetter`, `Type` and `Keyboard` are confusing because they look like the names of classes. Also, as a code review item consider a more object oriented design - you could create an object representing each type of vehicle containing the weekly and daily rates for each.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that you need to consider:

- there is a missing break between the case F and case E, this means
  that the rate F will be replaced with the rate E
- The logic to compare rates (line 53) shouldn't be applied only to the case 'E', that should be out of the switch statement.
- There is no option to validate the rate with the daily options (if the amount of days is less than 7 it will be out of the cycle (check your logic to calculate 'rate1').
- You should be using a debugger to verify the values assigned to the program (an automated unit test with JUnit or testNG will become handy)
- If you don't have a debugger, `System.out.println()` can be useful to verify the values assigned, just remember to take them out.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd and 3rd if stmt in your 1st if block. Move it outside